# Reflection using QMetaType (Class instantiation by name)

Tags: c++, qt, reflection, qt5, instantiation

I want to instantiate a class regarding its name. I found that Qt allows it with `QMetaType::create`.
I also found that we have to register the class using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`.
But I did everything needed (I think), and it didn't work.

That's my basic class :

```
#ifndef     __BLOCK_HH__
# define    __BLOCK_HH__

# include   <QMetaType>
# include   <QObject>

# include   <string>
# include   <vector>

# include   "Util.hpp"
# include   "Common.hh"

class       Block
{
protected:
    std::string _name;
    uint32      _u32StartAddr;
    uint32      _u32EndAddr;
    uint8       *_pu8Content;
    bool        _bSure;
    bool        _bVirgin;
    std::string _type;

    std::vector<std::string>    _errorCauses;

    Block(const std::string&, uint32, uint32, uint8 *, const std::string&);

public:
    Block(const std::string& = "", uint32 = 0, uint32 = 0, uint8 * = 0);
    Block(const Block&);
    virtual ~Block();

    Block&  operator=(const Block&);

    void        setName(const std::string&);
    void        setStartAddr(uint32);
    void        setEndAddr(uint32);
    void        setContent(uint8 *);
    void        sure();
    void        notSure();
    void        erase();

    const std::string&  getName() const;
    uint32              getStartAddr() const;
    uint32              getEndAddr() const;
    uint8               *getContent() const;
    bool                isSure() const;
    bool                isVirgin() const;
    const std::string&  getType() const;

    void            addError(const std::string&);
    void            dumpError(std::ostream& = std::cerr) const;

    virtual void    dump(std::ostream& = std::cout) const;
    virtual void    parse();

    virtual bool    operator<(const Block&) const;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Block)

#endif
```

That's one of the inherited class :

```
#ifndef     __CSS_HH__
# define    __CSS_HH__

# include   "Block.hh"

typedef struct
{
    uint32  boot_lma;
    uint32  boot_vma;
    uint32  boot_length;
    uint32  boot_entry;
    uint32  nb_of_param;
} t_css;

class       CSS : public Block
{
    uint32  _u32BootFlashAddr;
    uint32  _u32BootSdramAddr;
    uint32  _u32BootSize;
    uint32  _u32Bep;
    uint32  _u32CpuClock;
    uint32  _u32SdramSize;
    bool    _bEncram;

public:
    CSS(uint32 = 0, uint32 = 0, uint8 * = 0);
    virtual ~CSS();

    virtual void    dump(std::ostream& = std::cout) const;
    virtual void    parse();

    uint32  getBootFlashAddr() const;
    uint32  getBootSdramAddr() const;
    uint32  getBootSize() const;
    uint32  getBEP() const;
    uint32  getCpuClock() const;
    uint32  getSdramSize() const;
    bool    encramEnabled() const;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CSS)

#endif
```

And that's the piece of code I use to instantiate :

```
Block       *Mapper::constructBlock(const std::string& name, uint32 u32Start, uint32 u32End, uint8 *pu8Content)
{
    Block   *block = 0;
    int32   i32Id = QMetaType::type(name.c_str());

    if (i32Id != QMetaType::UnknownType)
    {
        block = static_cast<Block *>(QMetaType::create(i32Id));
        if (block)
        {
            block->setStartAddr(u32Start);
            block->setEndAddr(u32End);
            block->setContent(pu8Content);
            block->parse();
        }
    }
    return (block);
}
```

The name I give here will be "Block" for the class Block and "CSS" for the class CSS. But `QMetaType::type` always return `QMetaType::UnknownType`.
Maybe I forgot something to register the class. Have you an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to register the type with [`qRegisterMetaType()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-2) to make the name available at runtime. [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) makes the type known at compile time to Qt functions based on templates.